# Can you add a math related site to the "Trilogy"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, math-se

A SO style site for math questions seems like it would do well.  It would be a helpful place for questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202343) one about the probability of rolling a certain dice combination.

Is there any chance that a math related site will be opened?

Comment: Although not specified the question, you cite, as the asker, I can say it is actually programming related. I'm writing an algorithm to double check a program I wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one for serious mathematics of interest to the academic/research community:

https://mathoverflow.net

Be sure to read [its FAQ](https://mathoverflow.net/faq) before posting!

Comment: I think there wasn't one when the question was asked. Judging from comments on other answers, ever StackExchange wasn't ready.

Comment: Yes, there wasn't.  However, now, there is!

Comment: Speaking as somebody who did very well as a math undergrad, and has taken math courses since, they've got a special tag for questions I can understand without difficulty:  `soft-question`.

Comment: -1. Mathoverflow is for Serious mathematics of interest to the academic/research community. They do not welcome questions about the kind of math problems/questions that are often asked on this site. IMHO this answer should be unaccepted. SLaks: nothing personal, it's just that mathoverflow gets recommended often w/o people understanding what it's for. There is still a void for a math site to refer people to.

Answer (score 20):

We now have https://math.stackexchange.com which is targetted for math at all levels.

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory answer:

You can start your own with [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Until it's released (in 6-8 weeks, of course) StackExchange is vaporware to me.

Comment: @David: Unless they rename it StackExchange Forever, I'm holding out hope.

Comment: I doubt the quality of StackExchange sites versus say the OG sites (stackoverflow, serverfault, etc). Stackoverflow has a full team of developers building a framework to solve the exact problems faced by stackoverflow. I really hope this isn't true, but a stackexchange site is likely to be a second class citizen to stackoverflow.

Comment: Also if you feel like starting one, I'm totally down, 129 a month split 2 ways isn't that costly.

Answer (score 3):

It would be great, but we'd need a VERY GOOD EDITOR to be able to input all of the math constructs.

Comment: http://texify.com/ would work nicely

Comment: Why ? In tex, in mathml, in programming ... in all those, math expressions are expressed using regulra text.