# What sister sites should be added to the family of Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: discussion, sister-site

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can you add a math related site to the “Trilogy”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10802/can-you-add-a-math-related-site-to-the-trilogy)
>   [*.Stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/-stackoverflow-com)

I can think of a couple:

1. "Math Overflow" - math is generally not subjective and questions can be answered in a straightforward manner, but the questions do not necessarily belong on Stack Overflow because often they aren't programming-related.
2. A goof-off site. One where the users are not directed to follow any specific category or subject, and can post whatever they want. This will undoubtedly result in a lot of humor and nonsense, but would certainly make for good entertainment.

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate, but I can't find anything exactly like it.

Comment: I had this sort of problem on SU. Took me about 10 minutes just to find the duplicate...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10802/can-you-add-a-math-related-site-to-the-trilogy/10851#10851

Comment: Troggy, I found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/stackoverflow-com.. but I sort of remember seeing some other one about this too

Answer (score 0):

Math-overflow would quickly be filled with assignment questions.

Also, please don't encourage the start of *more* goof-off sites on the internet, there's enough of them already.

Answer (score -1):

I think what we're really missing is a feel good site where anyone can post anything and everyone votes everything up.  I nominate [www.specialsnowflakes.com](http://www.specialsnowflakes.com).

Comment: How about www.warmcudlyupvotes.com? :)

Answer (score -1):

I can see some mileage in a business, career development, and/or project management overflow (Meetings Overflow, perhaps?) - questions related to those subjects crop up relatively frequently and draw some flak, right or wrong.