# A math site similar to StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, math-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you add a math related site to the “Trilogy”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10802/can-you-add-a-math-related-site-to-the-trilogy)

May I suggest adding a math/science sister site to the family. [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is apparently [only for research mathematicians](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s) and they do not accept student questions. Also that site is apparently not part of the same family but is hosted by someone else.

The purpose for such a site would be asking questions related to mathematics, physics and other related areas, much in the same fashion that we do here on SO.

Comment: If we add MathOverflow to the SU/SO/SF trilogy - where does it end? There's bound to be more requests like this for other StackExchange sites. Our footer bar is only so big >_<

Comment: @rlb, sure, like this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41908

Comment: Anyway it's *maths*

Comment: On SO, we generally ask and answer questions as professional software people.  I'd suggest that MathOverflow *is* similar, only stricter.

Comment: @Downvoter: please could you include the question title in the URLs you post; it saves having to click through to see which question you are linking to. Many thanks!

Comment: ok @eth, i will from now on

Answer (score 3):

You can go create one yourself at http://stackexchange.com

Mathoverflow is not part of the stackoverflow family of sites.

You can ask stackexchange related questions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: +1 but not quite what I am looking for. I cannot afford to pay $129 per month for such a site as I have no commercial interest on it. Is getting another beside ServerFault, Super User and StackOverflow out of the question?

Comment: All signs post to yes

Comment: @Downvoter : MathOverflow _is_ a Stack Exchange site, look here : http://stackexchange.com/directory/list?sort=4
@Tronic : Are you wanting MathOverflow to be "an affiliate" like SO, SU, SF, and listed in the footer ?

Comment: @rlb, I know it is, he wants another kind of math site, read his question carefully please. Also, stackoverflow is not stackexchange

Comment: @rlb.usa - When he says that Mathoverflow is not part of the stackoverflow family, he is correct. That only relates to SO, SU and SF. It is a stackexchange site, but those are not part of the "trilogy". Minor, but important difference. SE sites use the same engine, but the people who host it control all the rules themselves.

Comment: @rlb, yes. I'd like to link my accounts and I want it to have similar rules as the three sites do.

Comment: @Tronic - Please see my answer to rlb's question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41908/careeroverflow-footer-link-associate-accounts-option/41916#41916 with regards to the difference between the Trilogy and StackExchange and the account linking.